# Javascript onfocus / onblur issues

Tags: javascript, onblur, livesearch

So I am making a little searchbar that shows results underneath of it like such:

```
<div id='searchWrapper'>
  <div id='Search'>
    <input id="inputSpn" type="input" value="" />
    <input id="searchBtn" type="image" src="/search.png" />
    <br clear='all'/>
  </div>
  <div id='Results'>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am basically doing a livesearch with through AJAX. The `<div id='Results'>` is initially hidden until you type and it populates some results. My issue however is getting it to hide when the user clicks away. having it disappear through `onblur` does not work either as I need to be able to click on the results and not have them disappear on me. Unfortunately I have not been able to find a good non jQuery method on the internet yet. Simplest way to put it is: I want the results to disappear if anything but the `<div id='searchWrapper'>` is clicked. Thanks!

Comment: If jQuery: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259716/how-to-blur-the-div-element),
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165411/how-do-i-hide-a-div-when-it-loses-its-focus), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547981/jquery-how-to-hide-a-div-when-user-clicks-on-anything-but-that-div-no-overlay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a non-optimised but working non-jQuery solution

```
<script>
document.onclick=function(e) {
  var elem = e?e.target:event.srcElement;
  var id = elem.id;
  document.getElementById("inputSpn").value=id+" clicked"; // debug - remove when happy
  // the following could be done by looping over the searchWrapper and its children
  if (id !="searchWrapper" && id!="Search" && id != "inputSpn" && id != "searchBtn" && id != "Results") {
    document.getElementById("Results").style.display="none"
  }
}
</script>
<div id='searchWrapper'>
  <div id='Search'>
    <input id="inputSpn" type="input" value="" />
    <input id="searchBtn" type="image" src="TekTP/icons/search.png" />
    <br clear='all'/>
  </div>
  <div id='Results'>hello
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

Toggle if clicked on the wrapper div

```
 var hide= (id !="searchWrapper" && id!="Search" && id != "inputSpn" && id != "searchBtn" && id != "Results");
document.getElementById("Results").style.display=(hide)?"none":"block";
```

Comment: You are welcome :) PS: I think the <br> should be outside the div before the results div

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to the document (using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)) - [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8qKc4/4/)

```
<style>
#Results {
     display: none;   
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        if(document.getElementById('searchBtn') != (event.target) ? event.target : event.srcElement) {
            document.getElementById('Results').style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('Results').style.display = 'block';
        }
    });
};
</script>

<div id='searchWrapper'>
    <div id='Search'>
        <input id="inputSpn" type="input" value="" />
        <input id="searchBtn" type="button" value="Search"/>
        <br clear='all'/>
    </div>
    <div id='Results'></div>
</div>
```

But if you are going to be using a significant amount of Javascript in your site, you might consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) - it will make your life much easier.

Comment: Non-IE solution and it will hide if anything but the search button was clicked

Comment: Never claimed it was an IE solution. If the asker wants JS that works well cross-browser, the asker should consider using a library.

Comment: or just added the ternary test for event.target/event.srcElement